# Copy string array for pasting to LibreOffice Calc

Tags: vb.net, copy-paste, libreoffice-calc

How do I copy an array of strings to the clipboard to paste to OpenOffice or LibreOffice?

This CSV version works for Excel, but not for OpenOffice or LibreOffice.

Input example = "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"

[image: Desired output (next row after every 8 columns)]

Here is my current code:

```
 Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click

    ' This returns array of strings for csv
    Dim csvparts As String() = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Dim csv As String = ""

    Dim rowCounter As Integer = 0
    For Each part As String In csvparts

        csv += ("""")

        For x As Integer = 0 To spinbox.SelectedIndex
            csv += (part)
            If spinbox.SelectedIndex > x Then csv += (vbLf)
        Next
        csv += ("""")

        rowCounter += 1

        'Next row after every 8th column
        If rowCounter > 7 Then
            rowCounter = 0
            csv += (vbLf)
        Else
            csv += (",")
        End If
    Next

    Dim dataObject = New System.Windows.DataObject()

    Dim bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv)
    Dim stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
    dataObject.SetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue, stream)

    System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: csv is csv. If it works in excel it should work in openoffice. Can you show the csv file that you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it working. Save your csv as Unicode Text to the clipboard. I did csv(for Excel) and UnicodeText(for Open/LibreOffice)

```
    Dim dataObject = New DataObject()

    Dim cbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv)
    Dim cstream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(cbytes)
    dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue, cstream)

    Dim bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(csv)
    Dim stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
    dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText, stream)

    Clipboard.Clear()

    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, True)
```